# Notepad++ brace overwriting

Tags: notepad++

I've been primarily coding in Coda for the past couple years, and am now trying to familiarize myself with Notepad++ for the Windows side of things. I figured out how to enable the brace autocompletion, but I'm wondering if there is any way in N++ to have the editor "type over" or "overwrite" braces so you don't end up with duplicates?

As in... if I type a parenthesis, and the character immediately after my cursor WAS a parenthesis, it should simply be overwritten, not entered again.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there's a plugin for that.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but this might be of interest to new visitors.

Yes this is possible using `XBrackets Lite` plugin (latest version 1.2.1). You can download it from the `Plugin Manager` or from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XBrackets%20Lite/).

When installed, go to `Plugins > XBrackets Lite > Settings...`, check `Autocomplete brackets` and leave unchecked the `Even if corresponding right bracket exists`. That's all!

[image: screenshot]

Please note that this solution isn't perfect. Consider the following example, where `|` is the place of your cursor:

```
if ($x==1) |

}
```

and you press `{`, it will autoclose the bracket resulting to

```
if ($x==1) {|}

}
```